# Release static int variable

Tags: iphone, variables, static, uiview

How to "clean" static int variables in a view class method? Every time a get back to this view I need those vars "zeroed". The `[self.view removeFromSuperview];`
instruction does not seem enough to free up memory from those vars.

Thank you. Have a great 2010!

These int vars are declared static in a view method. They are not global in the view class.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a static value to stick around, don't make it static.

Comment: That's a point. I want the static values to stick around as long as I'm on their view. Right after going away from that view..puff, their gone. When I get back to their view, I want them already "zeroed". Like local vars. These int vars are declared static in a view method. They are not global in the view class. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for instance variables. If you keep your view around even after it's disappeared, why not just zero the instance variables in `-viewWillAppear:` or `-viewDidDisappear`?

Comment: AFAIK, when allocing a static variable that is defined inside a function (or method), you really can't release it later.

Comment: @bentford I believe you can actually release it later on, so long as we're talking Objective-C objects. Calling one `static` does not affect its retain count in any way — it's still up to you to retain it if you want to hold on to it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually do this by defining a setValue method similar to:

```
@interface MyClass 
{
  // ...
}
+ (NSString *)myVar;
+ (void)setMyVar:(NSString *)newVa;
@end

@implementation MyClass
static NSString *myVar;
+ (NSString *)myVar { return myVar; }
+ (void)setMyVar:(NSString *)newVar { myVar = newVar; }
@end
```